# Confluent Platform docker cluster on 3 linux diffrent machines in cluster

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

We are searching the documentation that explain how to install confluent platform via docker on 3 different linux machines as cluster

We are plan to build the following cluster

We have 3 redhat Linux machines , while on each machine we want to install:

```
kafka 
schema registry 
zookeeper
```

After review on confluent documentation we have not succeeded to find what we are plan , or maybe we not search well

So can we get help – about what is the right confluent documentation about confluent docker cluster with 3 different linux machines?

What we found until now is that

1. Install docker kafka confluent &  schema registry and zookeeper , on single linux machine
2. Install docker kafka cluster with 3 kafka docker & 3 schema registry & 3 zookeeper servers on single Linux machine

But we not found procedure to install Kafka &  schema registry & zookeeper on each machine while total machine are 3 in cluster

Comment: Maybe you should share what you've tried? Multinode documentation for Kafka can be found at https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/multi-node.html#cp-multi-node
 
But I'm still not sure I understand why you are convinced that using Docker is better than just using Ansible to install a cluster on your machines https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-ansible.html#cp-ansible-playbooks

Comment: Dear cricket_007 , the link that you gave me https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/multi-node.html#cp-multi-node , is about configuration of the multi node but what about multi node installation from scratch ( include the description of docker-compose.yml for multi node ?, so how to find multi node kafka docker installation ?

Comment: @cricket_007 , do you have 3 diff docker-compose.yml examples files for cluster with 3 nodes ( while each docker-compose.yml  file include kafka & zookeeper & Schema )

Comment: Docker-Compose is primarily meant to be used on one machine, by default. You would need Docker Swarm, at the least, [with an overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#multi-host-networking). Otherwise, you can use `docker run --net=host`, and setup all the port mappings between each machine just as if everything wasn't running in Docker. Again, it's not clear what you tried, so what issues are you having? Also, I have seen no examples with more than one schema registry, but I would suggest starting with 1 of each container on separate machines.

Comment: Dear @cricket_007 , I found this link https://github.com/shivsantham/Dockerized-Multi-Node-Kafka-Cluster , and we intend to build three docker kafka nodes in cluster that include on each machine also zookeeper and schema registry , do you think by using this examples from the link is enough to manages 3 nodes in cluster?

Comment: @cricket_007 about what you asked - "it's not clear what you tried" , so I will tell you , until now we install on one docker machine - kafka + zookeeper and schema registry ( all images are from confluent ) , so the next step is to build cluster with muti nodes

Comment: @cricket_007  ,   about what you said - "docker run --net=host, and setup all the port mappings between each machine" can you help me to understand if the configuration of the docker-compose.yml according to the link - https://github.com/shivsantham/Dockerized-Multi-Node-Kafka-Cluster is include the "port mappings" built in ?

Comment: @cricket_007  , is it really possible to build and configured docker cluster without Docker-Compose ?

Comment: @KingDavid Not sure I understand your question. Yes... I've done it with individual `docker run --network` commands. Kubernetes/Openshift/Mesos/Nomad don't use Compose files.

Comment: @cricket_007  , I think she asked if the Compose files can include all configuration without using - docker run --network commands

Comment: @jessica Those instructions seem correct, but they use old `confluent/` Docker images rather than the current `confluentinc/` ones. The general idea is that you just list the external IP address + port of each of the machines rather than do `zookeeper:2181`, for example like you'd have on one machine.

Comment: @KingDavid Docker-Compose just forwards its configuration to a `docker run` anyway, plus a few more extras (like a default network), so either way could be used. Docker-Swarm would be the recommended way to run one command from one machine rather than deploy separate compose files.

Comment: Dear @cricket_007 so if they are only for confluent and not for confluentinc , can you help me please to search the right docker-compose.yml  that should to fit to cluster with multi nodes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202018/discussion-between-king-david-and-cricket-007).

Comment: @KingDavid All those commands should work just fine. Just replace the image names. Please try.